# IP/PORT forward requests to another server

Tags: networking, server, port-forwarding

I have the following listening PORT:IP set up on my UBuntu server.

```
12.345.67.890:3636
```

It receives requests perfectly, however, I would now like to forward any requests to that IP:PORT to another IP:PORT, i.e.:

```
09.876.54.321:3636
```

Essentially I want to do a request forward `12.345.67.890:3636 -> 09.876.54.321:3636`.

How can I go about it in Terminal and if I wanted to change it back how can I go about that too? Is there also a way to test that the data is forwarding and it is setup properly?

Thanks!

Edit: Can I just do as follows, just wondering how I would go about testing it and how I could disable it?

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3636 -j DNAT --to-destination 09.876.54.321:3636
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Disabling is easy: `iptables -F`.

Comment: Disabling `iptables -F` does not work in Ubuntu 18.04.2 - but `iptables -F -t nat` does the trick.

Comment: To change it back run the same commands with `-A` changed to `-D`. This deletes those rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands in your question are enough to enable routing and forward **12.345.67.890:3636** to **09.876.54.321:3636**.

---

Use iptables' LOG target to monitor what is happening:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG
```

You should see something like this in /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug 19 08:43:23 hostname kernel: [190951.964227] IN=eth0 OUT=eth0 SRC=11.22.33.44 DST=09.876.54.321 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51600 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41960 DPT=3636 WINDOW=246 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

- SRC: Source IP address
- DST: Destination IP address
- SPT: Source port
- DPT: Destination port

---

Flush iptables rules to clean up everything:

```
iptables -F
```

Comment: Thanks @EricCarvalho I've implemented and checked, and it's all working :) Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## Disabling the port forwarding

When it comes to **removing the port routing capability**, no answer was given that would switch off the forwarding (experimentally verified on Ubuntu 18.04.2).

Credits: The question by @DT.DTDG is greatly precisely stated, thanks.  This question plus @Eric's answer have helped me solving something, thanks!  And I went further in researching this topic, so I want to share the knowledge with the community.

#### Purging the rules

In order to clean up the routing rules,  you need to remove them from the NAT routing table (Network Addres Translation table).  You achieve this by that:

```
iptables -F -t nat
```

Otherwise: if you miss out "-t nat" parameter, the rules mentioned in the question will continue working (e.g. in Ubuntu 18.04.2).

#### Switch off forwarding

Additionally, the kernel-parameter needs a separate command.  If you want to get all cleaned up you also have to:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

It is generally [strongly adviced not to enable](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/2017-03-01/finding/V-38511) forwarding of packets between interfaces **in systems that are not routers**, for security reasons.

## Appendix

1. All actions typically need escalated priviledges, run them preceded with `sudo` or as "root".
2. Ad-acta. Commands that configure the routing:

CUR_PORT = current machine port
DES_IP   = destination machine IP address
DES_PORT = destination machine port

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport CUR_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination DES_IP:DES_PORT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: After running 
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport CUR_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination DES_IP:DES_PORT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

I lost internet connectivity. I couldn't even curl internal ports.

What does the second line do?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar and stumbled upon this.

Ran the two commands given in the questions. And things broke. I was not able to curl google.com, not even curl services running on the same server.

The culprit was the second command.

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This creates a rule in iptables such as

```
21     286 19120 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Deleting this rule fixed the issue.

In order to delete the above rules change `-A` to `-D` in the same commands like so:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8585 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.101:80
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```